# DBus NameOwnerChanged

Tags: arch-linux, i3, macintosh, d-bus, polkit

When i run dbus-monitor --system, i got these 20 events per second:

```
signal time=1585510053.359267 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2019 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5379"
   string ":1.5379"
   string ""
signal time=1585510053.368805 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2020 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5380"
   string ""
   string ":1.5380"
signal time=1585510053.377872 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2021 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5380"
   string ":1.5380"
   string ""
signal time=1585510053.707381 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2022 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5381"
   string ""
   string ":1.5381"
signal time=1585510053.710534 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2023 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5382"
   string ""
   string ":1.5382"
signal time=1585510053.719271 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2024 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5381"
   string ":1.5381"
   string ""
signal time=1585510053.719633 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2025 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5382"
   string ":1.5382"
   string ""
signal time=1585510053.730048 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2026 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5383"
   string ""
   string ":1.5383"
signal time=1585510053.738336 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2027 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5383"
   string ":1.5383"
   string ""
signal time=1585510053.749230 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2028 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5384"
   string ""
   string ":1.5384"
signal time=1585510053.758894 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=2029 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.5384"
   string ":1.5384"
   string ""
```

When i run in console mode, i dont get these errors and my cpu is much cooler, but when i do startx, i got these errors and these process are using a lot of cpu :

```
polkitd --no-debug 

dbus-deamon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
```

I run on arch-linux, i3, on a macbook pro.